# How to use Mock setup for nullable types

Tags: c#, testing, moq, nullable

I have an interface which has nullable parameters like this

```
Result<Notice> List(int offset, int limit, Guid? publicationId, Guid? profileId, DateTime? toDate, ListingOrder order);
```

This is how I attempted to mock this this method

```
mockNoticesClient.Setup(c => c.List(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<Nullable<Guid>>(), It.IsAny<Nullable<Guid>>(), It.IsAny<Nullable<DateTime>>(), Data.Notices.ListingOrder.DateDesc)).Returns(dataNotices);
```

Then when trying to use the method

```
var results = this.noticesClient.List(0, 100, null, profileId, latestNoticeTime, Data.Notices.ListingOrder.DateDesc);
```

Whenever this line is run though this exception is thrown

```
... threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' ... {System.NullReferenceException}
```

I have tried a few different combinations like using setup with null in the parameter but this doesn't work either. I am using Moq 4.0.10827 which is the latest version (at present).

**Edit:**
The constructor for the noticesClient takes the interface for the dataNoticesClient

```
public Client(Data.Notices.INotices noticesClient)
```

and initalised like this

```
mockNoticesClient = new Mock<Data.Notices.INotices>();
noticesClient = new Client(mockNoticesClient.Object);

mockNoticesClient.Setup(c => c.List(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<Nullable<Guid>>(), It.IsAny<Nullable<Guid>>(), It.IsAny<Nullable<DateTime>>(), It.IsAny<Data.Notices.ListingOrder>())).Returns(dataNotices);

mockNoticesClient.Setup(c => c.List(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<Guid?>(), It.IsAny<Guid?>(), It.IsAny<DateTime?>(), It.IsAny<Data.Notices.ListingOrder>())).Returns(dataNotices);
```

Comment: What is `dataNotices`? Can you post the full stacktrace of the nullref exception? Which variable is null `results` or `noticesClient`? If `noticesClient` then you should check that it gets assigned.

Comment: Neither variable is null, its the parameters that the list method takes. For some reason Moq is throwing an error whenever a nullable parameter is actually entered as null

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace for the exception?

Answer (score 1):

This was the bug within `moq` library at the time when the question was raised(`moq 4.0.10827`) but it is solved [here](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/90). It is possible now to make setup with `Nullable<T>` and make invocation with `null`, works perfectly.

```
public interface INullable
{
    int Method(Guid? guid);
}

var mock = new Mock<INullable>();
mock.Setup(m => m.Method(It.IsAny<Guid?>())).Returns(6);
int a = mock.Object.Method(null); // a is 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I would debug this test and check the following:

```
Data.Notices.ListingOrder.DateDesc
```

One of the first three values might be null, hence `NullReferenceException` is thrown

BTW, such chaining may signalize a design flaw, see [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

Comment: The value of that is set, I have also tried using It.IsAny<..ListingOrder> (enum)

Comment: Provide how do you use the `mockNoticesClient`, where do you inject it and where do you obtain the `noticesClient`.